# Duplicate posts in custom query WordPress loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new to PHP and I'm experimenting with custom queries. I have a total of 5 posts which should be displayed over 2 pages of pagination. The code below displays 2 pages of pagination which repeats the first 3 blog posts. I can't figure out why it's showing the first 3 posts twice instead of showing all 5 posts once. Below is the code section in my index.php. Any help would be very much appreciated!

```
<?php

$args = array('post_type' => 'post');

$allPosts = new WP_Query($args);

while ($allPosts->have_posts()) {
    $allPosts->the_post(); ?>
    <h1 class="nobottommargin"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php 
the_title(); ?></a></h1>
    <p class="notopmargin">Posted by <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> in 
    <?php echo get_the_category_list(', '); ?> on <?php the_time('d/m/Y') ?>.</p>
    <p><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), 20); ?> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">read more &raquo;</a></p>
    <hr>
<?php } 

echo paginate_links();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the post per page argument.

```
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => 3,
 'paged' => $paged
  'post_type'=>'post'
);
```

Also you can add the arguments for paginate_links function.  [Check  paginate_links](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to make your custom query override the global `$wp_query` variable, which tricks the WordPress functions into thinking it is the main query. Then, once you’re done with pagination, add `wp_reset_query()` to set the query back to how it should be.

```
//WP_Query arguments
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
'post_type'              => ['post'],           
'posts_per_page'         => 10,
'paged'                  => $paged,     
'orderby'                => 'title', 
'order'                  => 'ASC',

);

//The Query
global $wp_query;
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

//The Loop
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
        $wp_query->the_post();
        //Do Stuff
    endwhile;
endif;

//Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

- Build your custom loop `$args`, and include `'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged'` )
- Overwrite `$wp_query` with your new one. So instead of

```php
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

you use

```php
global $wp_query; 
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```